# Assign null value to Formula Field in a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

Hello i have custom formula field name-sau__c on  custom object NEw__c.

In test class i need to passs null value to this formula field . to increase coverage of my code.

formula field -Sau__c  is having formula sk__r.Kite__r.Code___c;

Code__c is a  custom text field on  custom object Kite__c .

Comment: Are you trying to pass value for formula field  in test class?

Comment: yes  , but if i am trying to assign nulll directly then its sayin non writable field

Comment: You cannot assign a value for formula fields. Instead in Code__c field of Kite__c object make that value as null which intern results that formula field to null

Comment: thnaks but how to assign after making code__c field null , after that aslo when i am assigning it throgh refernce variable.field name its showing , non wriiteable

Comment: You need to create sk__c object and relate it to Kite__c object

Comment: could please give me some demo code of it not able to get this logic as i am very new to apex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula fields are non writable  fields. You cannot assign or edit those fields. Instead you need to assign null value to code__c field on Kite__c object as below.

This is just sample code. You need to populate necessary mandatory fields as pwe your org

```
Kite__c kt= new Kite__c();
kt.name='sample kite';
kt. Code__c='';
insert kt;

sk__c sk = new sk__c();
sk.name='sample sk';
sk.kite__c= kt.id;// Assiging Kite to sk__c object
insert sk;

NEw__c nw= new NEw__c();
nw.name='sample new';
nw.sk__c= sk.id;// Assigning sk to new__c object
insert sk;
```

As mentioned by @cropredy we can also use mocking formula fields, audit fields, and autonumber fields  using the JSON serialize/deserialize technique. By using [Sobject Fabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) API we can achieve the same.

Comment: while this is true; unit tests often just need SObjects rather than DML'd records. As such, mocking formula fields, audit fields, and autonumber fields can be done using the JSON serialize/deserialize technique. A very useful library to do this is [Matt Addy's SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) that I highly recommend.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy for pointing it. Adding the same to answer as well.

Comment: thanks for the logic this helped me a lot